# which more secure to build web apps with, php or python?

Tags: php, python, web-applications, programming-languages

which programming language is more secure to build web apps with, php or python?

Comment: This question is subjective.  See the FAQ:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Why so many down votes? Computer nerds need to feel superior about something on a Saturday night?

Comment: @Brad, this seems to fall into the 4th bullet category in the faq link u posted. I didn't see anything in the faqs requiring that questions meet a certain skill level...

Comment: @Abe Miessler, the question was closed by various moderators because it was subjective... it has no real answer.  It had nothing to do with the skill level of the question.  The first line of the second section in the FAQ states that these types of questions will be closed.

Comment: How is this subjective? Your answer seems accurate according to the SO community...

Comment: read this http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2010/Apr/119 (English) and this http://www.isecur1ty.org/news/vulnerabilities/245-java-deployment-toolkit-javaws-jnlp.html (Arabic) to know why i am asking.

Answer (score 11):

This has little to do with the language, and much to do with the code.

Comment: it can also be said that it has everything to do with the programmers code and level of security approach.